# How do I pass MySQL data on Fusion Chart using JavaScript and Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fusioncharts

Here I have uploaded two screenshots. I want to display MySQL data in this gauge. I am using JavaScript and Node.Js for MySQL database connectivity.

Fusion Chart Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    let fusionCharts= document.querySelector('#chart-container')   

    FusionCharts.ready(function() {

        var fusionCharts = new FusionCharts("chart-container",{
            "type": "angulargauge",
            "renderAt": "chart-container",
            "width": "450",
            "height": "250",
            "dataFormat": "json",
            "dataSource": {
                // Chart Configuration
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "",
                    "lowerLimit": "0",
                    "upperLimit": "100",
                    "showValue": "1",
                    "numberSuffix": "%",
                    "theme": "fusion",
                    "showToolTip": "0"
                },
                // Chart Data
                "colorRange": {
                    "color": [{
                        "minValue": "0",
                        "maxValue": "50",
                        "code": "#F2726F"
                    }, {
                        "minValue": "50",
                        "maxValue": "75",
                        "code": "#FFC533"
                    }, {
                        "minValue": "75",
                        "maxValue": "100",
                        "code": "#62B58F"
                    }]
                },
                "dials": {
                    "dial": [{
                        "value": "80",
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        fusionCharts.render();
    });
```

How to replace chart value('80') by MySQL data.

MySQL Database Connectivity Code

```
const mysql=require("mysql");    
const express=require("express");    
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");    

var app=express();    
app.use(bodyParser.json());    
var mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({    
    host: "localhost",    
    port: 3306,    
    user: "username",    
    database: "mydb",    
    password: "password",    
});    

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{    
    if (!err){    
        console.log("Wow! Connection Established");    
    }    
    else{    
        console.log("Opps! Connection Failed");    
    }    
});    

mysqlConnection.connect(function(err){    
    if (!err);    
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT Temperature FROM ISL201 ORDER BY ISL201.Timestamp DESC", function(err, results){    
        if (!err);        
        console.log(results);    
    });    
});
```

Comment: Post code, not images of code. The problem is simple: you haven't set up any routes. Your node code simply establishes two connections, prints stuff to the console, then quits. You need to follow this basic [tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) to set up a route that sends back the mysql data, then request the according URL in your html page.

Comment: I have uploaded codes. Now check, please.

Comment: Actually, I am doing this first time. So, If you would help me with my code then it will be much better.

Comment: I've already looked at your code. Like I said, you aren't using express anywhere. You need to set up routes. Use the GET route from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) and instead of sending back text, use [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) to send back the mySQL data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that you can use to render FusionCharts using the above technologies

Server.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
var app = express();
//Configuring express server
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//MySQL details
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "fusioncharts_jspsample",
  multipleStatements: true
});

mysqlConnection.connect(err => {
  if (!err) console.log("Connection Established Successfully");
  else console.log("Connection Failed!" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});

//Establish the server connection
//PORT ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}..`));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});


app.get("/api/number_of_visitor/:id", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM number_of_visitor WHERE id = ?",
    [req.params.id],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(rows);
      } else console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
```

Client Snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Angular Gauge</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function fetchData(id = 1) {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/number_of_visitor/${id}`
        );
        return data;
      }

      Promise.all([fetchData()]).then(v => {
        console.log(v);
        let val = v[0][0].bakersfield_central;
        const ds = {
          chart: {
            caption: "Customer Satisfaction Score",
            subcaption: "Last week",
            lowerLimit: "0",
            upperLimit: "22500",
            lowerLimitDisplay: "Bad",
            upperLimitDisplay: "Good",
            showValue: "1",
            valueBelowPivot: "1",
            theme: "fusion"
          },
          colorRange: {
            color: [
              {
                minValue: "0",

            maxValue: "7500",
            code: "#e44a00"
          },
          {
            minValue: "7500",
            maxValue: "15000",
            code: "#f8bd19"
          },
          {
            minValue: "15000",
            maxValue: "22500",
            code: "#6baa01"
          }
        ]
      },
      dials: {
        dial: [
          {
            value: val
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
      var cSatScoreChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: "angulargauge",
        renderAt: "container",
        width: "400",
        height: "250",
        dataFormat: "json",
        dataSource: ds
      }).render();
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Used POSTMAN for serving the requests.

In case you are still facing a problem, here is a demo (SQL file included) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6am59m3cemfslat/database_demo.zip?dl=0